# Teams bot SSO without dialogs framework. Invalid x5t claim

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm following this tutorial:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-sso/7-exercise-bots-sso
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/Teams/80%20Using%20Single%20Sign-On%20with%20Microsoft%20Teams/Demos/02-learn-msteams-sso-bot
- https://youtu.be/cmI06T2JLEg
- https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

The bot worked as expected. But I would like not to use the dialog framework. I'm having trouble adapting the model.

In the personal scope I reply to a message with an oauth card:

```js
const oauthCard = await CardFactory.oauthCard(SsoConnectionName, undefined, undefined, undefined, {
  id: 'random65jHf9276hDy47',
  uri: `api://botid-${MicrosoftAppId}`
})
await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.attachment(oauthCard))
```

so i get the token on the handler

```js
handleTeamsSigninTokenExchange(context, query) {
  if (context?.activity?.name === tokenExchangeOperationName) {
    console.dir(context?.activity?.value)
    token = context?.activity?.value?.token
  }
}
```

What am I supposed to do with this token? I get the `Invalid x5t claim` error when I try to use microsoft client like this:

```js
msGraphClient = microsoft.Client.init({
  debugLogging: true,
  authProvider: done => {
    done(null, token)
  }
})
```

```
// on message 'whoiam'
const me = await msGraphClient.api("me").get()
```

Is this the correct token? How do I initialize the Microsoft Graph client with this token?

My repo sample: https://github.com/itacirgabral/teamsbotSSOdemo/blob/nodialog/nodialogs.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet for initializing the Graph Client:

```
// Get an Authenticated Microsoft Graph client using the token issued to the user.
    this.graphClient = Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, this._token); // First parameter takes an error if you can't get an access token.
        }
    });
```

Refence sample link:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs/server/models/simpleGraphClient.js

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs/server/api/appController.js

Comment: The sample are using dialogs framework too (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs/server/dialogs/mainDialog.js). I found a different oauth card initialization (https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/userTokenAccess.ts). Graph client initialization snippets are equivalents, aren't they?

Comment: Can you please try with the code snippets provided in sample and check it once?
Please let us know if you are facing any issue here.

Comment: the code sample work as expected. I can run the demo smooth. The demo doesn't cover my needs and the correct outh card initialization is hidden inside the 'dialogs framework'. why does use oauth prompt's 'dialogs framework'?

Comment: Can you please go through this documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots

Comment: I'm looking for it yet. It i was not the correc token. Could you delete your answer? It induces people to go wrong. https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/oauthPrompt.ts#L94-L107

Comment: If I try to delete the answer, our whole conversation will be disabled in this case.
It's better, if you can provided/post your final answer, so that I can update/delete it accordingly?
Also, it is not the verified answer.